# Running Grunt, Unable to connect to localhost

Tags: macos, terminal, gruntjs, yeoman

I am running a yeoman app when I run the server everything passes, but I get this odd port for the server,

```
Matt-MacbookPro:places mattbtay$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task


Done, without errors.

Running "compass:server" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles/ 
   create .tmp/styles/main.css (7.533s)
Compilation took 7.536s

Done, without errors.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on ::1:9000.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

I would normally just want to load "localhost:9000" and the server would run find. But as it currently is, I have to enter that manually, is there something I have changed on my system that would be connecting to ::1:9000?

Comment: Strange... that almost looks like a bad IP address/port combination. Perhaps it's trying to connect to a specific IP address, failing, and somehow adding the default port number (9000) to the end? can we see your Gruntfile to look for any issues?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `::1` is not a port, it's an [IPv6 localhost address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).
Looks like your Grunt tries to use IPv6, perhabs your system is confgiured to prefer IPv6.

Run `$ ifconfig` and make sure that IPv4 line is present on `lo` interface: `inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0`.
If you can see only `inet6 addr: ::1/128`, when you simply don't have IPv4 enabled/configured.

No IPs should be hard-coded into Grunt configuration generated by Yeoman - it looks up the IP bound to `localhost`. Check out `connect` task configuration in https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/templates/common/Gruntfile.js.
You should have sth similar in your local Gruntfile.